# Poll prediction using R

Tags: r

The topic is based on the presidential poll prediction. The question that needs to be answered is given below:
The questions that need to be answered as follows. I am interested mostly in the second question:

** Question 1**

We will begin by using the market prices on the day before the election to predict the 2008 election outcome. To do this, subset the data such that it contains the market information for each state and candidate only on the day before the election. Note that in 2008 the election day was November 4. We compare the closing prices for the two candidates in a given state and classify a candidate whose contract has a higher price as the predicted winner of that state. Which states were not classified correctly?

** Question 1 solution code**

```
intrade08 = read.csv("intrade08.csv")
pres08 = read.csv("pres08.csv")
intresults08 = merge(intrade08, pres08, by = "state")
intresults08$margin = intresults08$Obama - intresults08$McCain
intresults08$day = as.Date(intresults08$day)
intresults08$DaysToElection = as.Date("2008-11-04") - intresults08$day
intresults08$price_margin = intresults08$PriceD - intresults08$PriceR
poll_pred = rep(NA,51)
st.names = unique(intresults08$statename)
names(poll_pred) = as.character(st.names)

for(i in 1:51){
  state_data = subset(intresults08, subset = (statename == st.names[i]))
  last_day = subset(state_data, DaysToElection == (DaysToElection == 1))
  poll_pred[i] = mean(last_day$price_margin)
}

misclass = pres08$state.name[sign(poll_pred) != sign(pres08$margin)]
misclass
```

** Question 2**

How do the predictions based on the betting markets change over time? Use the classification procedure as above on each of the last 90 days of the 2008 campaign rather than just the day before the election. (Hint: Use a loop.) Plot the predicted number of electoral votes for the Democratic party nominee over this 90-day period. The resulting plot should also indicate the day of the election and the actual election result.

** Question 2 solution code try**

```
ob = mc = rep(0,90)
for (i in 1:90){
  polls_day = subset(intresults08, DaysToElection == (DaysToElection <= 90-i+1)) 
  for (j in 1:51){
    state_data = subset(polls_day, statename == st.names[j])
    obama_st = mean(state_data$PriceD, na.rm = T)
    Mc_st = mean(state_data$PriceR, na.rm = T)
    if(obama_st > Mc_st){
      ob[i] = ob[i] + EV[statename[j]]

    }
    else if(obama_st < Mc_st){
      mc[i] = mc[i] + EV[statename[j]]
    }
    else{
      ob[i] = ob[i] + ev[statename[j]] / 2
      mc[i] = mc[i] + ev[statename[j]] / 2
    }
  }
}

plot(90:1, ob, type = 'l', col = 'blue',
     xlab = 'Days to the election', ylab = 'Electoral votes')
```

It doesn't seem to be correct as the prediction doesn't change with the time. Please help. The data sets can be found in the following links given.

https://github.com/kosukeimai/qss/tree/master/PREDICTION

Comment: This question is more suitable for `Cross Validated` and `Data Science`. Please add it there.

Comment: Please improve your question. First, if you're not really interested in question 1, remove it so it doesn't take away the attention you want for question 2. Then, please share some toy data (`dput(head(data))` could do), as some people don't like downloading files from the internet. Then, show us what you've done and how it failed.